CPU to Switch SGMII port with PCIE 2.5Gb
I can't seem to find a 2.5 Gbps Ethernet controller that could be a bridge between the SGMII+ port and PCIe.
this is what I want to do:

I don't want to use PHY (from the copper 2.5G to 2.5G SGMII)
I225 and AQC112C are for copper link so I can't connect them directly to switch with SGMII. In this case I'm looking for alternative solutions, Is that doable?

I'm also looking, and so far only found the intel i350 which is complicated and only running at 1G. Or something even more unwieldy like the intel 82599...
